# Как создать запрос с условием сравнения параметров при помощи JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Я хочу создать запрос, который будет выбирать баннеры по полю `ReqName` категории и, если в категории более одного баннера, отображать баннер с большим полем цены.

Я использую запрос `JPA`. Мне удалось создать запрос, который выбирает баннеры по категории `ReqName` и отображает текст. Могу ли я использовать `JPA`, не прибегая к `Specification`, чтобы сделать такой запрос, описанный выше?

Repository:

```
List<Banner> findByCategoryReqName(String req_name);
```

Test:

```
Iterable<Banner> test = bannerRepository.findByCategoryReqName("First");
test.forEach(t-> System.out.println(t.getText()));
```

Вывод:

```
SecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecond
FirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов несколько:

#### 1. Используя [синтаксис именования методов](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Ближе всего к требуемому (выбрать сущность из заданной категории с максимальной ценой) будет "*получить полный список сущностей заданной категории, упорядоченный по цене*".

Итого, метод будет выглядеть примерно так:

```java
List<Banner> findByCategoryReqNameOrderByPriceDesc(String req_name);
```

по выполнению этого метода нужно будет забрать из полученного списка первый элемент (`Desc` - сортировка по убыванию)

#### 2. Используя [синтаксис именования методов](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) и [ограничения выдачи результатов](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Пункт появился по комментарию [@Roman Konoval](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-konoval).
Метод можно задекларировать следующим образом:

```
Banner findFirstByCategoryReqNameOrderByPriceDesc(String req_name);
```

Имхо - это будет оптимальный вариант.

#### 3. Используя [NativeQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query.native)

Здесь всё зависит от того, какая СУБД используется. К примеру, для MS SQL метод может выглядеть так:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM BANNERS WHERE req_name= ?1 ORDER BY Price DESC", nativeQuery = true)
Banner findMaxByCategoryReqName(String req_name); // возможно, лучше использовать Optional<Banner>, если категория может быть пуста.
```

#### 4. Используя [@Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Возможно, тут тоже можно задействовать что-то вроде TOP 1 или LIMIT 1, но быстрый поиск не нашел упоминаний подобного.

Comment: Для автосгенерированного запроса тогда уж `findFirstByCategoryReqNameOrderByPriceDesc`, который вернет один `Banner`. Смотрите https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: @RomanKonoval Класс! В упор не видел этого функционала, спасибо!